# Get value from another dataframe - Spark

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I have two dataframe as below,

```
df_table = spark.read......load()
df_table_count = df_table.count().show() 
df_values = spark.createDataFrame([("First App", "User")], ["Application", "Created By"]).show()
```

This provides me a result as below

for df_table_count,

**100**

for df_values

[image]

and i wanted to merge both the dataframe and get the result together as below,

[image]

I tries joining,

```
df_values = df_values.join(df_table_count, on=["row_index"])
```

but below error is triggered,

**'int' object has no attribute '_jdf'**

Let me know the right way of getting result of a value from another dataframe

Comment: `df_table_count` is not a dataframe. the `count()` will result in an integer value of the number of records. so, a join won't work. you can just create a new column using `withColumn()` and feed in the count value

Comment: I tried that as well, but the error is 'None Type' object has no attribute 'withColumn'

Comment: can you please add that try to the question as well? we can help you debug. also, remove the `show()`. You don't need that when assigning a variable. `show()` does not return a dataframe. it returns nothing and hence you might ne getting that NoneType error

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in your code.

`df_table_count = df_table.count().show()` does not return a dataframe. The `count()` will return an integer value, and you don't need the `show()`.

`df_values = spark.createDataFrame([("First App", "User")], ["Application", "Created By"]).show()` does not return a dataframe due to the `show()` used here. `show()` *returns* nothing, so `df_values` is a NoneType object having nothing. The correct syntax is -

```
df_values = spark.createDataFrame([("First App", "User")], ["Application", "Created By"])  # returns a dataframe and is stored in the variable
df_values.show()  # prints the top 20 records and returns nothing
```

Now, your case can be solved in a couple of ways - creating a column, or [`crossJoin`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-crossjoin) in case `df_table_count` is a dataframe. Since, `df_table_count` is an integer value, it'll be easy to use a `withColumn()`.

```
df_values = spark.createDataFrame([("First App", "User")], ["Application", "Created By"]). \
    withColumn('source_count', func.lit(df_table_count))
```

P.S. - the [`lit()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lit.html#pyspark-sql-functions-lit) is used in input literal values.

Answer (score 0):

Say your `df_table.count()` is 100:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit,row_number,col

df_table_count = 100 

df_values = spark.createDataFrame([("First App", "User")], ["Application", "Created By"])

df_values\
          .withColumn('source_co', lit(df_table_count))\
          .show()
+-----------+----------+---------+
|Application|Created By|source_co|
+-----------+----------+---------+
|  First App|      User|      100|
+-----------+----------+---------+
```